# Why won't my washer spin even though it still agitates?

Tags: repair, appliances, washing-machine, troubleshooting

I have a Kenmore 80 series washer and it recently stopped spinning and agitating and I found out it was the coupler. So I changed that and it start to work again, normally. After a week or two it stopped spinning during spin cycle, but it still agitates. I did some research and tests and this is what I came up with over the past two days:

- The coupler is fine
- The pump isn't clogged. It spins fine and drains fine.
- The lid switch works perfectly
- While the agitator is spinning, I can stop it by holding it with my hand from making a rotation forward or backwards. I couldn't do that before
- I can spin the tub with my hands with about 5-10lbs of resistance.
- The clutch under the tub doesn't spin during spin cycle.
- When I change speed settings(medium to low or to high) for the agitator, the speed doesn't change.

From doing searching I think that it could possibly be the Gearcase/Transmission, the Tub Hub, or the Belt, if it has one and that is as much as I know.

Please help me figure this problem out. Its pretty annoying not having a working washer :/

Comment: The model number is 110.29842991

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure how the drive elements connect up on this. I know there is no belt. Gear box seems very unlikely. You should examine how the agitator attaches to the drive shaft below the top cap of the agitator. Sounds like it's slipping, and if that's the case, it may not be able to spin either. If it works differently than I think, it could be the clutch slipping. To get to the clutch is major surgery. You'd have to remove the agitator and would discover any slipping parts here on your way to the clutch any way.

Comment: I recently ordered a washer spanner wrench, a clutch kit, and a tub hub/drive block. I will take it apart and replace these parts. hopefully it fixes the problem. I will report back

Comment: I replaced the clutch and it still didnt fix the problem but I think the washer was still in need of a new clutch cause the tub is very hard to spin by hard now.

Comment: Sounds like you accomplished needed work, but disappointing result none the less. I'm not familiar enough with this machine to offer much more advice. If the drive shaft is spinning but the clutch is not, some connection between the two must be slipping or disconnected.

Comment: I ordered a transmission recently and will replace that in a few days. I will post back with the results

Answer (score 0):

There is a switch under the lip of the top where the post depresses a metal flange to trigger the drain and spin cycle. Believe it or not, the return mechanism under that switch is a rubber band. Yes, I wrote that correctly, a rubber band and when it gets old it breaks and the switch stops working. There are two small phillups screws. Unplug your machine, undo those screws, drop the mechanism, replace the rubber band, replace the mechanism and it will work. The repair man wanted $100 to "repair" my machine and I looked at the switch myself. A five cent rubber band repaired the problem. Careful to not allow the depress flange to fall out of the mechanism or you'll go nuts trying to make it fit again. Replace the band, screw it back into place, plug the machine back in and it will work. Trust me.

Comment: Thanks, Tom.
My Kenmore 80 Series stopped spinning and made no noise, so I figured it might be a switch or a fuse. After I read about your rubber band problem, I unscrewed the lid switch and saw that it was a different mechanism inside a small plastic box, but the box had separated at the seam in the middle from the lid pressure, making the switch inoperable.
I wrapped the box tight with some teflon tape that was handy (several turns in opposite directions) and reinstalled it. Worked great again.